# C# : The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net

I can't figure out my mistake while going through [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s3p7.html).

The following output:

```
Warning    1    Possible mistaken empty statement    (Line    32)
Error    2    The name 'i' does not exist in the current context    (Line    35)
Error    3    The name 'i' does not exist in the current context    (Line    36)
```

is obtained with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Loops
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void btnForLoops_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int loopStart;
            int loopEnd;
            int answer;
            //store the numbers from the text boxes into the two new variables:
            loopStart = int.Parse(tbLoopStart.Text);
            loopEnd = int.Parse(tbLoopEnd.Text);
            for (int i = loopStart; i <= loopEnd; i++) ; 
            {
                answer = answer + i;
                listBox1.Items.Add("i = " + i + "answer = " + answer.ToString()); //the display shows as i=1 answer = 1, i=2 answer = 3, etc...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 for (int i = loopStart; i <= loopEnd; i++) ;
                                            ^
```

The semicolon at the end should be removed.
Else, the compiler sees that as the end of the loop and your `int i` exists only within the loop itself.

Hence the error.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate your quick response. Now I am still stuck with my 'answer' variable: "Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'answer'

Comment: Change it to `int answer = 0;` instead of `int answer;`. The variable is unassigned and that is triggering the error.

Comment: That worked, yeah!! You folks are the best!! Best wishes:)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a `;` after your `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

; after the for-loop, take it out.